# Cakephp:Model linking

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new with `cakephp`, actually I want to show the all the list of subjects which is belong to one subject category. I have made a subject model which code is below:

#### subjects.php

```
<?php
class Subject extends AppModel
{
 var $name='Subject';
var $belongsTo = 'Subjectscat'; 
}

?>
```

and subject category model is:

#### subjectscats.php

```
<?php
class Subjectscat extends AppModel
{
 var $name='Subjectscat';
var $hasMany=array('Subject');
}

?>
```

#### subjectscats_controller.php

```
<?php
        class SubjectscatsController extends AppController
        {
        var $name='Subjectscats';
        var $helpers = array('Html', 'Javascript', 'Ajax');
        var $components = array('Auth');
        var $uses=array('Subject', 'User','Subjectscat');


        function index()
        {
         $this->layout = 'internal';
         $session_id=$this->Session->read('User.id');
         $username = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' =>$session_id)));
         $this->set('session_id',$username);
         $this->Subjectscat->recursive =1;
         $cat = $this->Subjectscat->find('all');
          $this->set('subjectcategory',$cat);
         }
          function isAuthorized() {
            return true;
         }

}

?>
```

and the view which is located such that:

#### views\Subjectscats\index.ctp

```
<table><tr><td colspan="3">View Feedback</tr>
 <?php debug($subjectcategory) ?> <?php echo $html->link('Add Feedback', '/feedbacks/add', array('class'=>'button')); ?>
<?php print_r($subjectcategory); ?>
<?php foreach($subjectcategory as $subject_cat)

{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $subject_cat['Subjectscat']['cat_name'];?></td>
<?php print_r($subject_cat['Subjectscat']['Subjects']); ?>
</tr>
<?php }
?>

 </tr>
</table>
```

and it give this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index:  Subjects [APP\views\subjectscats\index.ctp, line 10]

```
-- Table structure for table `subjects`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subjects` (
  `id` bigint(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `subjectscats_id` bigint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `subjectscats_id` (`subjectscats_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subjects`
--

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`id`, `subjectscats_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'English'),
(2, 1, 'Hindi');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `subjects`
--
ALTER TABLE `subjects`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `subjects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectscats_id`) REFERENCES `subjectscats` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes wish developers to pay more attention to details.

The notice you're getting is coming from this line:

```
print_r($subject_cat['Subjectscat']['Subjects'])
```

If you replace that line with this one you will see why:

```
debug($subject_cat)
```

"Subjects" key does not exist in your array, all models are singular, remember? What you need to do there is a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($subject_cat['Subject'] as $subject)
{
    // output stuff you need from $subject
}
```

Remember the [debug() function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/699/debug), it is a great tool. Another way to debug your stuff is the excellent [debug_kit](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/debugkit-1-1-released) [plugin](http://thechaw.com/debug_kit/versions); very easy to set up and very, very useful.